# How to efficiently pass infrequent messages between an ASP.NET page and a Windows Service?

Tags: asp.net, windows-services

**The tl;dr version:**

Is there an easy way for an aspx page to push a message to a Windows service w/out the service constantly polling a shared resource (e.g. database table)?

**The tl;but-I-read-it-anyway version:**

I've got an ASP.NET web app that implements a very long running process.  I understand that a common way to side-step issues due to app pool recycling and requests timing out (for example) is to create a Windows service to handle the long-running process outside of IIS.

I'm comfortable w/ ASP.NET and I've built simple windows services before, but I could use some advice on how best to pass messages between the web page and the windows service.

The obvious easy solution is to use a shared database - the web page writes a request to a "jobs" table and the service monitors that table to know when to process the job.  However, I'm not sure that's a good fit for the way my app is used.

The app is basically a hopped-up email newsletter mailer (with some caveats that make it slower than your typical SMTP mail merge).  It gets used once every few days, on average, and a typical use case is to send several short email jobs and then one or two long ones.  So the "send email" code, which is what I want to move the windows service, can take anywhere from a few seconds up to 20 minutes (and growing) to execute.

So it seems that for the web app to be responsive at the short end of the scale, the service would have to poll the database every couple of seconds so that users aren't waiting longer for the job to start than it would take to execute.  But that seems like a lot of useless load on the database for the days at a time when the app isn't used at all.

I've seen examples that use System.Diagnostics.Process to let an aspx page run a console application, which seems closer to how my app is actually used (if I were to put the mail code in the console app), but I don't think that gets it out from under the IIS process.

So my question boils down to: is there an easy way for a web page to push a message to (or otherwise provoke a reaction from) the windows service w/out the windows service constantly polling a shared resource (e.g. database table)?  Or is that constant db polling less of an issue than I think it is?

Further details: the web app targets the 3.5 framework and is running on an old backwater IIS 6 box.  In my research, I've run across info on MSMQ, [WCF/WAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734677.aspx), even [.NET Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but they all feel like overkill and my time budget for this problem leaves me enough time to learn *something* new, but not enough to parse and compare all three (or spend too much more time down the google rabbit hole).

I'm really just looking for a simple lightweight way to move some code out from under the IIS process.

Answer (score 3):

How about [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx)? You get the messages you want to email reliably delivered, and the server reads from the queue how ever frequently you like.

It's really simple to setup:

- Install MSMQ
- Create a private Queue (private queues don't get replicated on every machine on your domain)
- Use a tool like QueueExplorer to view the messages, or the built in MMC interface (right click my computer->manage -> services and applications->message queue)

Here's some very quick, *untested code* as an example. You can create your own formatters for the message if needed, and use transactions if the messages need the redundancy.

```
// System.Messaging.Dll
// The ASP.NET sends the messages to MQ:
using (MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(@"computername\private$\test", QueueAccessMode.Send))
{
    using (Message message = new Message())
    {
        message.Priority = MessagePriority.Normal;
        message.Label = "A label";
        message.Body = "<content>The email message</content>";

        message.UseDeadLetterQueue = false;
        message.Recoverable = false;
        message.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter();

        queue.Send(message);
    }
}

// The service reads the queue in a loop:
// (more sophisticated than this)
MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(@"computername\private$\test", QueueAccessMode.SendAndReceive);
queue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter();
Message message = queue.Receive();
string xml = (string)message.Body;
```

Comment: What I've read about MSMQ so far makes me think it's overkill for my purposes. I'll admit I don't really grok it, but it seems like a lot of overhead for my little app.

Comment: @Matt MSMQ is really pretty simple to use, and it does exactly what you want. Messaging is preferable to a straight service call, because there is no dependency on both components being up at the same time and especially long running processes can be queued up and executed when you have time. On top of all that, it tends to be more error resilient, if your mail app crashes it can restart the last job when it comes back up.

Comment: @Matt it's a lot simpler than you'd think, I've updated my answer.

Comment: OK @Chris, you've convinced me to give MSMQ a second look. :) The overhead I was worried about was the "install MSMQ" step, mostly because I've witnessed a couple twitter rants about difficulties with configuration etc.  I agree the code doesn't look that hard, but I'm not confident I fully understand the implications of switching from a straight service call to a messaging approach.  "queued up for later execution" sounds good from a reliability standpoint, but I still need pretty much immediate execution for the short run-time use case. I guess it's a good thing I think prototypes are fun.

Answer (score 1):

Well, WCF is really simple solution and I am using it ASP.NET application for this exact purpose, newsletter server - windows service that sends newsletters. I didn't have any problems with performace at all. Here is a good example of simple WCF IPC :

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

update:
In my example windows service is server and in OnStart I am doing something like this (example is simplified):

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
  host = new ServiceHost(typeof(NewsletterNotifier), new Uri[]{ new Uri("net.pipe://localhost") });
  host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(INewsletterNotifier),  new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "PipeNewsletterNotifier");
  host.Open();
}
```

(Don't forget to close host in OnStop service event, and on pause and continue you should also handle this)

And then when ASP.NET application wont's some services from Newsletter server (defined in INewsletterNotifier) :

```
ChannelFactory<INewsletterNotifier> pipeFactory = new ChannelFactory<INewsletterNotifier>( new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/PipeNewsletterNotifier"));
INewsletterNotifier pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
pipeProxy.DoSomething();
```

Comment: Thanks Antonio, that looks promising.  Just to be clear, are you saying that I can run a WCF Server as a windows service w/out any dependency on IIS?  Some of the other stuff I've read about WCF/WAS (w/out digging into the technical details) implied that life would be a lot easier w/ IIS 7, while I'm still on IIS 6 for this project.

Comment: yes server is in Windows Service, WCF ServiceHost is instantiated on Windows service OnStart and ASP.NET application is client. Since the both applications are on same server I am using Named Pipes as transport. I will update my answer with these details

Comment: thanks for the clarification and added detail. That jibes with some other stuff I found related to the content of your link, and should be enough to get me started on a quick prototype.  I'll follow up once I get through that.